# For loop getting out of control?

Tags: php

I have put together a for loop for a small search function I am building.

The code is as follows

```
$keyword = explode("+", $keywords);
    for($i=0; $i <= count($keyword); $i++){
        //check user table
        $q = "SELECT id, username FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '%$keyword[$i]%'";
        $result = $database->query($q);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            extract($row);
            echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=$id'>$username</a>";
    }
}
```

When this runs, it is somehow retrieving all of the users from the database.
Is there any obvious reason for this?

If `$keywords = "gregg";` , would this still work as there wouldn't be a + sign (only one word). Either way, this still doesn't work when it has multiple words involved!

I can confirm the query works perfectly if the term 'gregg' is passed into it.

Thanks for reading, hope you can help.

Comment: You have a nexted loop with a SQL Query inside. This is not good. Consider refactoring the code to use one or no loop and in the process you will find the problem.

Comment: Todd: Assuming 'username' is unique (in this case, it sounds like it is), the while loop would only execute once (he is using it because he is used to the way that that code looks).  Therefore, its not a big issue of having the while loop there...it just doesn't do anything different than getting rid of it.

Comment: Your loop should read `for($i=0, $j = count($keyword); $i <= $j; $i++){` this will prevent the count of `$keyword` from being calculated with each pass of the loop. FYI.

Comment: Fixed now, thanks for the feedback!! Todd, what would you suggest that is better? More efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop looks like:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($keyword); $i++)
```

This is going past the end of $keyword by one, so the last query the loop executes is "LIKE '%%'" which would return every row.  To fix this, change it to:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($keyword); $i++)
```

Also, you cannot do "$keyword[$id]".  It must be "{$keyword[$i]}"

Answer (score 0):

your index has count($keyword) - 1, not count($keyword);

```
$keyword = explode("+", $keywords);
    for($i=0; $i <= count($keyword) - 1; $i++){
        //check user table
        $q = "SELECT id, username FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '%".$keyword[$i]."%'";
        $result = $database->query($q);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            extract($row);
            echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=$id'>$username</a>";
    }
}
```

and changed quotes

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$q = "SELECT id, username FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '%{$keyword[$i]}%'";
```

or better this

```
$q = "SELECT id, username FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username LIKE '%" . $keyword[$i] . "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider use `OR` in the sql:

```
$keyword = explode("+", $keywords);
$keywords = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $keywords);

$q = "SELECT id, username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR username LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%';";
$result = $database->query($q);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=$id'>$username</a>";
}
```